# Why links generated with @Url.Action in JavaScript are not in lowercase when using AttributeRouting?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas, attributerouting, url-action

I have this code in a JavaScript function:

```
var url = '@Url.Action(MVC.Membership.User.ActionNames.Update, MVC.Membership.User.Name)';

url += "?userName=" + userName;

ul.append("<li><a href=" + url + "\>" + userName + "</a></li>");
```

`Membership` is an [`Area`](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/wiki/Areas). I'm using [`T4MVC`](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/) to refer to Controller and Action names to avoid magic strings... :)

This `JavaScript` code is part of `View` that resides in the `Membership` Area.

`UserController` is decorated this way:

```
[RouteArea("Membership")]
public partial class UserController : BaseController
```

and the `Action` method is this one:

```
[GET("Users/Update/{userName}")]
public virtual ActionResult Update(string userName)
```

The route I get in the link is this:

```
http://localhost:8087/membership/User/Update?userName=leniel
```

I expected it to be:

```
http://localhost:8087/membership/users/update?userName=leniel
```

So my question is: why the link is not in lowercase since all other links in the app are being generated with lower case letters? Is this not supported or am I forgetting some config related to [AttributeRouting](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting) or the Area setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the [feedback](https://github.com/mccalltd/AttributeRouting/issues/89#issuecomment-7385470) from AttributeRouting creator... turns out it was my bad.

Now I understand the problem...

If I do this:

```
var url = '@Url.Action(MVC.Membership.Permission.ActionNames.GrantRevoke, MVC.Membership.Permission.Name, new { area = "Membership", roleName= "Teste" }, null)';
```

The URL is generated correctly:

```
var url = '/membership/permissions/grantrevoke/teste';
```

but if I do this:

```
var url = '@Url.Action(MVC.Membership.Permission.ActionNames.GrantRevoke, MVC.Membership.Permission.Name, new { area = "Membership" }, null)';
```

I get this:

```
var url = '/Membership/Permission/GrantRevoke';
```

It's clear that I need to pass the roleName parameter.